Measurability with respect to product measure when one measure is the counting measure.
Problem statement
This problem is found in Rodyen & Fitzpatrick, Real Analysis, 5 ed, Problem 45(i) (pp. 232), or Problem 4(i) (pp. 422) in 4 ed.

Let $(X, \cal{A}, \mu)$ be a complete measure space, and $(\mathbb{N}, 2^{\mathbb{N}}, c)$, where $c$ is the counting measure. Consider $\mathbb{N} \times X$ with the product measure $c \times \mu$.   
Show that a subset $E$ of $\mathbb{N} \times X$ is measurable with respect ot the product measure space if and only if for each $k$, $E_k = \{x \in X: (k, x) \in E\}$ is measurable with respect to $\mu$.

Most problem I had revolves around the definition of the product measure.
Definition
Fitzpatrick defined the measurable rectangles as measurable sets of finite measure, and the product $\sigma$-algebra as the sets measurable with respect to the outer product measure.

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu), (Y, \mathcal{B}, \nu)$ be two measure spaces.  
A set $A \times B \subset X \times Y$ is a measurable rectangle if $A \in \mathcal{A}$, $B \in \mathcal{B}$, and $\mu(A), \nu(B) < \infty$.  
Let $\mathcal{R}$ be the collection of measurable rectangles in $X \times Y$, and define
$$
  \lambda (A \times B) = \mu(A) \cdot \nu(B) , \quad A \times B \in \mathcal{R}.
$$
Then $\lambda$ is a premeasure on the semiring $\mathcal{R}$. The outer measure $(\mu \times \nu)^* = \lambda^*$ is induced by $\lambda$, and the product measure $\mu \times \nu$ is the Carathéodory extension of $\lambda$, defined on the $\sigma$-algebra of $\lambda ^*$ measurable set.

Attempt
$(\implies)$: Suppose $E \subset X \times \mathbb{N}$ is $(c \times \mu)$-measurable.
I saw that if one defines the $\sigma$-algebra of $(c \times \mu)$-measurable sets to be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing measurable rectangles, then one can show that
$$
  \mathcal{S} = \{
    E \subset X \times \mathbb{N}: 
    E_k \in \mathcal{A} \textrm{ for all } k \in \mathbb{N} 
  \}
$$
is a $\sigma$-algebra containing all measurable rectangles. Then by the minimality assumption, $\mathcal{S}$ contains all $(c \times \mu)$-measurable sets.
However, in the current construction, the $\sigma$-algebra is no longer the smallest, so the above argument would not work.
$(\impliedby)$: Assume $E_k$ is $\mu$-measurable for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Since
$$
  E = \bigcup _{k = 1} ^{\infty} (\{k\} \times E_k),
$$
we know $E$ is $(c \times \mu)$-measurable if each $\{k\} \times E_k$ is also $(c \times \mu)$-measurable. The difficulty here is that we only take sets with finite measure as measurable rectangles. In case that $\mu(E_k) = \infty$, and it cannot be written as a countable union of finite measure sets, then it is unclear whether ${k} \times E_k$ is still $(c \times \mu)$-measurable even though $E_k \in \mathcal{A}$.
Similar questions had been asked in here and here, though there are no detailed answers.
Please leave an anwser or comment if you have any idea regarding this. Any help is appreciated.

Is $X$ assumed to be $\sigma$-finite here? The specification that $A$ and $B$ must have finite measure in order for $A\times B$ to be a measurable rectangle is a bit odd. Most sources I've seen tend to only require that $A$ and $B$ be measurable. If $X$ is always $\sigma$-finite this is a non-issue but if not then I'd be concerned with how the whole space $X\times\mathbb{N}$ is measurable.

$X$ is not assumed to be $\sigma$-finite, because in a later problem it asks to show Tonelli's Theorem holds without the assumption of $\sigma$-finiteness. The whole space is certainly measurable though, since it is the complement of the emptyset.

Let us go step by step.

For any $B \subseteq X$,
\begin{align*} 
\mu^* (B) &= \inf  \left \{\sum_{n = 1}^\infty  \mu (A_n): \forall n \in \Bbb N: A_n \in \mathcal{A},  B \subseteq \bigcup_{n \mathop = 1}^\infty A_n \right \} = \\
&= \inf  \left \{\sum_{n = 1}^\infty  \mu (A_n): \forall n \in \Bbb N: A_n \in \mathcal{A},  \mu(A) < +\infty, B \subseteq \bigcup_{n \mathop = 1}^\infty A_n \right \}
\end{align*}

From item $1$, we have that, for any $k \in \Bbb N$ and any $B \subseteq X$, $(c \times \mu)^*(\{k\} \times B)= \mu^*(B)$.

Now, given any  $E \subseteq \Bbb N \times X$, and any $k \in \Bbb N$, let $E_k = \{x \in X: (k, x) \in E\}$.

If $E \subseteq \Bbb N \times X$ is $(c \times \mu)^*$-measurable, then for any $k \in \Bbb N$ and any $B \subseteq X$, using items 1, 2 and 3, we have
\begin{align*} 
\mu^*(B) &= (c \times \mu)^*(\{k\}\times B) = \\ 
&= (c \times \mu)^*((\{k\}\times B)\cap E) + (c \times \mu)^*((\{k\}\times B)\cap E^c) = \\
 &= \mu^*(B\cap E_k) + \mu^*(B\cap E_k^c)
\end{align*}
So, for all $k \in \Bbb N$, $E_k$ is $\mu^*$-measurable. It means, for all $k \in \Bbb N$, $E_k$ is measurable with respect to $\mu$. (See remark in the end).

Now note that, given any $C \subseteq \Bbb N \times X$, $(c \times \mu)^*(C) =\sum_{k \in \Bbb N}\mu^*(C_k)$. To prove this, just aplly the definition of $(c \times \mu)^*(C)$ and use item $1$.

If $E \subseteq \Bbb N \times X$ such that, for all $k \in \Bbb N$, $E_k$ is is $\mu^*$-measurable, then, for any $D \subseteq \Bbb N \times X$,
\begin{align*} 
(c \times \mu)^*(D)&= \sum_{k \in \Bbb N}\mu^*(D_k) = \\
&= \sum_{k \in \Bbb N} [\mu^*(D_k \cap E_k)+\mu^*(D_k \cap E_k^c) ] = \\
&= \sum_{k \in \Bbb N} \mu^*(D_k \cap E_k) + \sum_{k \in \Bbb N} \mu^*(D_k \cap E_k^c) = \\
& =(c \times \mu)^*(D \cap E) + (c \times \mu)^*(D \cap E^c)
\end{align*}
So $E$ is $(c \times \mu)^*$-measurable.


Combining items 4 and 6, we have proved that a subset $E$ of $\mathbb{N} \times X$ is measurable with respect to the product measure space if and only if for each $k$, $E_k = \{x \in X: (k, x) \in E\}$ is measurable with respect to $\mu$.
Remark: In item 4 above, in the general case, we cannot conclude that, for all $k \in \Bbb N$, $E_k \in \mathcal{A}$.
For instance, consider $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ where $X=[0,2]$, $\mathcal{A}= \{ \emptyset , [0,2] \}$ and $\mu([0,2])= +\infty$. Then, clearly, for all $B \subseteq [0,2]$, if $B \neq \emptyset$, then $\mu^*(B)=+\infty$. It follows that, for any $C \subseteq [0,2]$, $C$ is $\mu^*$-measurable.
For any $F \subseteq \Bbb N \times X$, if $F \neq \emptyset$, $(c \times \mu)^*(F) =+\infty$ and, for any $E \subseteq \Bbb N \times X$, $E$ is $(c \times \mu)^*$-measurable.
Now, take $E = \{1\} \times [1,2]$. Then $E$ is $(c \times \mu)^*$-measurable, and $E_1=[1,2]$ is $\mu^*$-measurable, but $E_1 \notin \mathcal{A}$.

Thank you for your reply. I have a problem with the $\mu$-measurability. In your answer you showed if $E$ is $(\mu \times \nu)$-measurable than $E_k$ is $\mu^$-measurable, i.e. w.r.t. the outer measure induced by $\mu$. But I understand the problem as $E_k$ are $\mu$-measurable, meaning $E_k \in \mathcal{A}$ for all $k$. For instance if $\mathcal{A}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure, then some sets are $\mu^$-measurable but not $\mu$-measurable.

Another details I would like to query is the equality $(c \times \mu)^* (C) = \sum _{k = 1} ^\infty \mu^* (C_k)$. We know that $(c \times \mu)^$ is countably subadditive, so $(c \times \mu)^ (C) \leq \sum _{k = 1} ^\infty \mu^* (C_k)$, but I cannot immediately see why the reverse holds. Nonetheless I actually figured out how the ($\impliedby$) direction, or your 5 - 6, is handled, which I answered in another post.

@ムータンーオ , To prove $(c \times \mu)^(C) =\sum_{k \in \Bbb N}\mu^(C_k)$, just apply the definition of $(c \times \mu)^*$  and item $1$.  Don't use sub-additivity. I updated my answer to include this explanation.

Sorry, but I still do not quite see why $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ being complete implies $E \in \mathcal{A}$ whenever $E$ is $\mu^*$-measurable. Can you provide more details on this?

@ムータンーオ , You are right. Since $(X, \cal{A}, \mu)$ is NOT supposed to be $\sigma-finite$, the fact that $(X, \cal{A}, \mu)$ is complete does NOT imply that $E \in \mathcal{A}$ whenever $E$ is $\mu^*$-measurable. When $(X, \cal{A}, \mu)$ is $\sigma$-finite, it is a theorem that the Carathéodory extension is the completion of $(X, \cal{A}, \mu)$, and so if $(X, \cal{A}, \mu)$ is complete, then the Carathéodory extension coincides with $(X, \cal{A}, \mu)$.

@ムータンーオ ,  Important: To say that $E_k$ is measurable with respect to $\mu$ means that $E_k$ is $\mu^*$-measurable.
Note that, in the general case, we cannot conclude that, for all $k \in \Bbb N$, $E_k \in \mathcal{A}$. See the remark I added in the end of my answer.

@ムータンーオ , I gave you a detailed complete answer, would you kindly accept my answer?

Sorry for missing out. You said "Important: To say that $E_k$ is measurable with respect to $\mu$ means that $E_k$ is $\mu^*$-measurable". May you please tell on why this is the case, instead of $E_k \in \mathcal{A}$?

@ムータンーオ , When we want to say that $E_k \in \mathcal{A}$, we say that $E_k$ is $\mathcal{A}$- measurable.  Note that $E_k$ being $\mathcal{A}$- measurable independs on the measure $\mu$. Note that, in the general case (without $\sigma$-finite condition),  $\mathcal{A}$- measurability implies $\mu^$-measurability, but not the other way round. Moreover, under the conditions of your question, we can only conclude that $E_k$ is $\mu^$-measurable, but we can NOT conclude that $E_k \in \mathcal{A}$. (See remark at the end of my answer).

With how Fitzpatrick writes, I am quite sure that by $\mu$-measurable he refers to $E_k \in \mathcal{A}$. With that said, I guess this is either a typo on his end, or the problem does not make sense in the first place.
